# How to send messages between AWS VPCs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, vpn, amazon-vpc, aws-private-link

I'm trying to understand how to send integration messages between applications. In the following scenario:

[image]

1. User in `Application 1` generates a query.
2. That query gets sent to `Application 2`
3. Application 2 returns the results and sends it back to `Application 1`

My specific questions are the following:

1. Does `Application 1` need to do anything related to the `On-Premise Application`, or is that all the responsibility of the infrastructure of `AWS VPC 2' to figure out once receiving a request?
2. Once an AWS PrivateLink is established, is it just a matter of sending messages back-and-forth between the 2 AWS VPC addresses? If so, how do you send messages to these addresses?

Comment: Did you already decide what kind of AWS messaging you are going to use (there are three of them)? Did you read messaging system documentation.

Comment: There are lots of options here including VPC to VPC VPN connection, VPC peering between multiple VPCs, routing requests via API Gateway so no inter-VPC connectivity is required, decoupling applications via SQS message queues, VPC Lattice, App Mesh application-level networking, and more. You should probably spend a little more time reading about AWS e.g. [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-vpc-connectivity-options/amazon-vpc-to-amazon-vpc-connectivity-options.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "send messages between applications"? Are these HTTP requests? Your choice of messaging technology is separate from network configuration. In fact, some messaging technologies (eg Amazon SQS) would not require direct connectivity between the VPCs. So, your first job is to decide how the messaging should operate.